# Stop ActivityManager killing background Termux processes

Tags: command-line, termux

I've been trying to run a ssh and a http server on my non-rooted Android phone using [Termux](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Main_Page).

I've installed [Termux:Boot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux.boot) and [termux-services](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Termux-services) to run them.

The server processes run for a while after I release the wakelock but are then killed by the system:

```
09-23 13:25:21.592  4450  5008 I ActivityManager: KPU : put [com.termux] : 15433 K
09-23 13:25:21.592  4450  5008 I ActivityManager: Killing 25360:com.termux/u0a171 (adj 904): DHA:empty #17
```

I tried disabling the app power monitor (Setting -> Device maintenance -> Battery) but it doesn't seem to make any difference.

Save rooting the phone, or keeping a wakelock in place, is there any way I can stop the ActivityManager killing my processes?

Setup: Samsung Galaxy A5 with stock-rom
(Android 8 / Samsung Experience 9)

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Galaxy A5, but I have Galaxy A10s and this helped me:

1. Go to `Settings -> Apps -> Termux`.
2. Tap `Battery`.
3. Enable `Allow background activity`.
4. Open Termux.
5. In Termux notification, click `Acquire wakelock`.
6. Tap `Allow`.